# JButton add Object

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton

Is there a way to add an object to a JButton?
I know I did it some years ago in C# but does it work in Java?

```
public Shop(Item[] buyables) {

    ArrayList<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();

    for(int i = 0; i < buyables.length; i++) {
        Item item = buyables[i];
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setText(item.getName());
        // button.addExtra(item);
        buttons.add(button);
    }

}
```

So every button references to one object or holds one object so if one clicks the button, I can work with the object it holds.

Comment: This would be better suited to a `JList<Buyable>` with a suitable `ListCellRenderer` - or possibly a `JTable`.

Comment: in your code you are just creating an array of JButtons, I don't really get it.

Comment: `So every button references to one object or holds one object so if one clicks the button, I can work with the object it holds.` please explain this a more

Comment: Could you clarify your question?

Comment: what do you want to associate with a button? an action? a listener? the Item?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need this behaviour, the wonders of OO allows you to just add it:

```
public class JReferencingButton<T> extends JButton 
{
  private T value;

  public T getValue() 
  {
    return this.value;
  }

  public void setValue(T value) 
  {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```